# Sentence tokenization splits sentences where there is dialogue followed by 'he/she said', how can I fix this?

Tags: web-scraping, nlp, nltk, tokenize, corpus

I am extracting sentences from pdfs into an excel spreadsheet. It handles most cases fine, but when there is a dialogue which ends in ? or ! and is followed by something like 'he said.' it splits the quote and the 'he said' into separate sentences.

For example: *"Ingaba ibhasi isishiyile?" babebuza.* which means *"Has the bus left?" they asked.*
gets split into *"Ingaba ibhasi isishiyile?"* and *babebuza.*

How can I fix my code so it doesn't split these type of sentences?
Note that it's not just in the case of *babebuza* (they asked) it happens with all cases where the quotes ends in ? or !

This is what I have tried but no luck so far.

I tried to code for instances where a sentence ends in ?" or !" and is followed by a word/sentence that starts with a lower case letter- so that these get treated as one sentence, but this didn't give the desired outcome.

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import re
import glob

def exclude_page_numbers(page_text, page_elements, exclusion_regions):
    filtered_text = ""

    for element in page_elements:
        text = element["text"]
        x, y = element["x0"], element["top"]  # Get the x and y coordinates of the element

        # Check if the element falls within any exclusion region
        exclude = False
        for region in exclusion_regions:
            x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = region
            if x_min <= x <= x_max and y_min <= y <= y_max:
                exclude = True
                break

        if not exclude and not any(char.isdigit() for char in text) and not text.strip().isdigit():
            filtered_text += text + " "  # Add a space after each element

    return filtered_text


def extract_sentences(text):
    # Replace “ and ” with normal double quotes "
    text = text.replace("“", '"').replace("”", '"')
       
    # Replace ‘ and ’ with normal single quotes '
    text = text.replace("‘", "'").replace("’", "'")

    # Split text on occurrences of `.`, `!`, or `?` while considering quotation marks within the sentence
    sentences = re.split(r'(?<=[.!?])(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', text)
    sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in sentences]

    # Merge the closing quotation mark with the preceding sentence
    merged_sentences = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(sentences):
        if sentences[i].endswith('"'):
            if i + 1 < len(sentences):
                merged_sentence = sentences[i] + ' ' + sentences[i + 1]
                merged_sentences.append(merged_sentence)
                i += 2
            else:
                merged_sentences.append(sentences[i])
                i += 1
        else:
            merged_sentences.append(sentences[i])
            i += 1

    # Join adjacent sentences if the first sentence ends with ?" or !" and the second sentence starts with a lowercase letter
    final_sentences = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(merged_sentences):
        if i + 1 < len(merged_sentences):
            first_sentence = merged_sentences[i]
            second_sentence = merged_sentences[i + 1]
            if re.search(r'[?!]"?\s*$', first_sentence) and re.search(r'^[a-z]', second_sentence):
                joined_sentence = first_sentence + ' ' + second_sentence
                final_sentences.append(joined_sentence)
                i += 2
                continue
        final_sentences.append(merged_sentences[i])
        i += 1

    # Tokenize final sentences using nltk.sent_tokenize
    tokenized_sentences = []
    for sentence in final_sentences:
        tokenized_sentences.extend(nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence))

    return tokenized_sentences

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file_path):
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file_path) as pdf:
        num_pages = len(pdf.pages)
        text = ""
        for page in range(3, num_pages - 2):
            page_obj = pdf.pages[page]
            page_text = page_obj.extract_text()
            page_elements = page_obj.extract_words()  # Obtain the text elements and their positions
            filtered_text = exclude_page_numbers(page_text, page_elements, exclusion_regions)
   def scrape_sentences_to_excel(pdf_file_paths, excel_file_path):
    sentences = []
    for pdf_file_path in pdf_file_paths:
        # Extract text from PDF
        pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file_path)

        # Extract sentences from the text
        extracted_sentences = extract_sentences(pdf_text)
        sentences.extend(extracted_sentences)

    # Create a pandas DataFrame with a single column for sentences
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentences': sentences})

    # Write the DataFrame to an Excel file
    df.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)

    print("Sentences extracted and saved to Excel successfully!")

pdf_folder_path = 'C:/Users/Paige Cox/Desktop/Little Zebra Books/pdfs'  # Folder path containing PDFs
excel_file_path = 'C:/Users/Paige Cox/Desktop/Little Zebra Books/pdfs/sentence_corpus_xhosa.xlsx'  # Output Excel file path

# Specify the exclusion regions as (x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max)
exclusion_regions = [(42, 558, 359, 559)]  # Add your exclusion regions here

# Get a list of PDF files in the folder
pdf_file_paths = glob.glob(pdf_folder_path + '/*.pdf')

# Scrape sentences from PDFs and save to Excel
scrape_sentences_to_excel(pdf_file_paths, excel_file_path)
```